# Show existence of set $ \{ A_x : x \in \Bbb R \} $ that satisfies three properties

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

**Problem**:
Show there exists a set of sets $ \{ A_x : x \in \Bbb R \} $ s.t. :
$\bullet $ $ \forall x \neq y. A_x \cap A_y = \emptyset $
$ \bullet $ $ \bigcup_{x \in \Bbb R }A_x = \Bbb R $
$ \bullet $ $ \forall x \in \Bbb R. |A_x| = \Bbb \aleph $

**Answer** : Since we know $ |\Bbb R \times \Bbb R| = | \Bbb R | $ then there exists a bijection $ f: \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R $. Given $ x \in \Bbb R $ we'll define the set $ A_x = f[ \{ x \} \times \Bbb R] = \{ f( \langle x,y \rangle) : y \in \Bbb R  \} $ . [ Then the answer goes ahead to prove all three properties are satisfied]

**Question:** The set $ A_x $ given above is correct, but I wanted to know if you have an idea for another set, I tried really hard to sit on this problem but had no idea so I resorted to the answer above. I still think I couldn't have come up with an example straight ahead that satisfies all the three conditions ( nor come up with the example above ). Also, how would you approach the problem above?

Comment: Do you need $A_x$ for $x\in\Bbb R$ or it is suffice to take $x$ over a set of the same cardinality of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Do you mean by $\aleph$ that all $A_x$ are countable? (Usually, e.g. Wikipedia, denoted $\aleph_0$)

Comment: @TitoEliatron If you take $x$ over a set of the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, you can always relabel the sets to do the problem with $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @MichaelJesurum I know, but i don't know wether the OP wants an EXPLICIT construction of some teoretical one based on some bijection.

Comment: @TitoEliatron I need $ A_x $ for $  x \in \Bbb R $, these sets need to be generated by an arbitrary real number.

Comment: @nicrot000 Sorry I didn't know that alternative meaning. I meant that $ \aleph $ stands for an uncountable set.

Comment: Well, any construction I can think of, is based on some bijection between $\Bbb R$ and some other set (for example, $\Bbb R/\sim$, wher $x\sim y\iff x-y\in\Bbb Q$)